# "View As" option in Interface Builder stuck in one view

Tags: interface-builder, xcode8

I have multiple view controllers for my app and I've been working on one view at a time in Interface Builder to make sure they work on all screen variations. I used "View As" option quite frequently to see how UI looks in different screen sizes. I just finished working on one view controller and want to move onto another view to do the same. However, the "View As" option does not change the screen size of the new view which I have currently selected. Instead, it changes the screen size of the view controller that I worked previously. This option seems stuck with the first view controller.  Is that a bug or I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case if anybody runs into the same problem, here what I was doing wrong. I need to set Simulation Size value of the viewcontroller that I want to work on to "Fixed" instead of "Freeform". Otherwise, it won't work.